# All day event dates incorrect in calendar ListItems created in Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a single-day, all-day event in a SharePoint Online calendar list, using Graph API. If I specify a start time of 00:00 and end time of 23:59, I get a two-day event that starts the day before. It seems the only way I can get it to start on the day I want is to add an extra day to the start, in effect requesting an event that starts one minute *after* it ends. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/{sitename}:/lists/{listname}/items`

#### All-day, single-day event with start time 00:00 and end time 23:59 yields a 2-day event that starts a day early:

```
// Request:
{
    "fields": {
        "Title": "Test Event",
        "EventDate": "2018-08-31T00:00:00",
        "EndDate": "2018-08-31T23:59:00",
        "fAllDayEvent": true
    }
}

// Response: 2-day event starting the day before
"fields": {
    "EventDate": "2018-08-30T00:00:00Z",
    "EndDate": "2018-08-31T23:59:00Z",
    ...
}
```

#### Adding a day to the start time yields correct single-day event:

```
// Request:
{
    "fields": {
        "Title": "Test Event",
        "EventDate": "2018-09-01T00:00:00",
        "EndDate": "2018-08-31T23:59:00",
        "fAllDayEvent": true
    }
}

// Response - correct!
"fields": {
    "EventDate": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z",
    "EndDate": "2018-08-31T23:59:00Z",
    ...
}
```

Comment: What happens if you pass in _just_ the date (`2018-09-01`)?

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately it still starts a day early:
    "EventDate": "2018-08-30T00:00:00Z", 
    "EndDate": "2018-08-31T23:59:00Z",

Comment: That's using 2018-08-31 - if I use 2018-09-01 I get an event that starts on 2018-08-31T00:00:00Z and ends at 2018-09-01T23:59:00Z.

Comment: If you can always repro this issue, I think you can report an bug in the github issue list.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot! It does seem to repro every time I've checked.

Comment: Github issue here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2755